# Three.js custom Shader with Texture

Tags: opengl-es, three.js, fragment-shader, vertex-shader, texture2d

I want to write a custom shader which manipulates my image with three.js.
For that I want to create a plane with the image as a texture. Afterwards I want to move vertices around to distort the image.

(If that an absolute wrong way to do this, please tell me).

First I have my shaders:

```
    <script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexshader">
        attribute vec2 a_texCoord;
        varying vec2 v_texCoord;

        void main() {
            // Pass the texcoord to the fragment shader.
            v_texCoord = a_texCoord;

            gl_Position = projectionMatrix *
                          modelViewMatrix *
                          vec4(position,1.0);
        }
    </script>

    <script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fragmentshader">
        uniform sampler2D u_texture;
        varying vec2 v_texCoord;

        void main() {
            vec4 color = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord);
            gl_FragColor = color;
        }

    </script>
```

Where I don't really understand what the texture2D is doing, but I found that in other code fragments.
What I want with this sample: Just color the vertex (gl_FracColor) with the color from the «underlying» image (=texture).

In my code I have setup a normal three scene with a plane:

```
    // set some camera attributes
    var VIEW_ANGLE = 45,
        ASPECT = window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,
        NEAR = 0.1,
        FAR = 1000;

    var scene = new THREE.Scene();


    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR);
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 15);

    var vertShader = document.getElementById('vertexshader').innerHTML;
    var fragShader = document.getElementById('fragmentshader').innerHTML;

    var texloader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    var texture = texloader.load("img/color.jpeg");

    var uniforms = {
        u_texture: {type: 't', value: 0, texture: texture},

    };


    var attributes = {
        a_texCoord: {type: 'v2', value: new THREE.Vector2()}
    };

    // create the final material
    var shaderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        uniforms:       uniforms,
        vertexShader:   vertShader,
        fragmentShader: fragShader
    });

    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    var plane = {
        width: 5,
        height: 5,
        widthSegments: 10,
        heightSegments: 15
    }

    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(plane.width, plane.height, plane.widthSegments, plane.heightSegments)

    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
    var plane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, shaderMaterial );
    scene.add(plane);

    plane.rotation.y += 0.2;

    var render = function () {
        requestAnimationFrame(render);

        // plane.rotation.x += 0.1;

        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };

    render();
```

Unfortunately, after running that code I just see a black window. Although I know that if I use the `material` as material when creating the mesh, I can see it clearly.
So it must be the shaderMaterial or the shaders.

Questions:

- do I have to define the uniform `u_texture` and the attribute
  `a_texCoord` in my shader Material uniforms and attributes? And do
  they have to have the exact same name?
- How many vertices are there anyway? Will I get a vertices for every pixel in the image? Or is it just 4 for each corner of the plane?
- What value does a_texCoord have? Nothing happens if I write:

  ```
  var attributes = {
      a_texCoord: {type: 'v2', value: new THREE.Vector2(1,1)}
  };
  ```
- Or do I have to use some mapping (built in map stuff from three)? But how would I then change vertex positions?

Could someone shed some light on that matter?

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work by changing this:

```
    var uniforms = {
        u_texture: {type: 't', value: 0, texture: texture},
    };
```

To this:

```
    var uniforms = {
        u_texture: {type: 't', value: texture},
    };
```

Anyway all other questions are still open and answers highly appreciated.
(btw: why the downgrade of someone?)

Answer (score 1):

> do I have to define the uniform u_texture and the attribute a_texCoord
>   in my shader Material uniforms and attributes? And do they have to
>   have the exact same name?

Yes and yes. The uniforms are defined as part of the shader-material while the attributes haven been moved from shader-material to the BufferGeometry-class in version 72 (i'm assuming you are using an up to date version, so here is how you do this today):

```
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(...);

// first, create an array to hold the a_texCoord-values per vertex
var numVertices = (plane.widthSegments + 1) * (plane.heightSegments + 1);
var texCoordBuffer = new Float32Array(2 * numVertices);

// now register it as a new attribute (the 2 here indicates that there are
// two values per element (vec2))    
geometry.addAttribute('a_texCoord', new THREE.BufferAttribute(texCoordBuffer, 2));
```

As you can see, the attribute will only work if it has the exact same name as specified in your shader-code.

I don't know exactly what you are planning to use this for, but it sounds suspiciously like you want to have the uv-coordinates. If that is the case, you can save yourself a lot of work if you have a look at the [`THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/extras/geometries/PlaneBufferGeometry.js)-class. It already provides an attribute named `uv` that is probably exactly what you are looking for. So you just need to change the attribute-name in your shader-code to

```
attribute vec2 uv;
```

> How many vertices are there anyway? Will I get a vertices for every
>   pixel in the image? Or is it just 4 for each corner of the plane?

The vertices are created according to the `heightSegments` and `widthSegments` parameters. So if you set both to 5, there will be (5 + 1) * (5 + 1) = 36 vertices (+1 because a line with only 1 segment has two vertices etc.) and 5 * 5 * 2 = 50 triangles (with 150 indices) in total.

Another thing to note is that the PlaneBufferGeometry is an indexed geometry. This means that every vertex (and every other attribute-value) is stored only once, although it is used by multiple triangles. There is a special index-attribute that contains the information which vertices are used to create which triangles.

> What value does a_texCoord have? Nothing happens if I write: ...

I hope the above helps to answer that.

> Or do I have to use some mapping (built in map stuff from three)?

I would suggest you use the `uv` attribute as described above. But you absolutely don't have to.

> But how would I then change vertex positions?

There are at least two ways to do this: in the vertex-shader or via javascript. The latter can be seen here: http://codepen.io/usefulthink/pen/vKzRKr?editors=1010
(the relevant part for updating the geometry starts in line 84).